# Is an Elven Champion faster without a horse?

Tags: movement, actions, pathfinder-2e

He has a speed of 30, while his Steed Ally a speed of 40. If the enemy is within 80 feet, he can use the Command an Animal action to direct his horse to use two of its actions close the distance, and his remaining two actions to Strike.

However, should the enemy fire arrows from 300 feet, he is better off without his horse:

- **On foot:** In the first 3 rounds he closes 3 times 30 feet, and in the foruth he Strides one last time before Striking twice
- **Mounted:** It takes 4 rounds just to get there

Did I misunderstand something? If not, is this intentional, or just an unfortunate edge case?

---

I know that with the Imposing Destrier feat from level 10 the horse is actually faster, but that is beside the point right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rules-as-Written, an Elf can move faster on foot than on the Horse; with exceptions

The biggest one being armor - if you are wearing heavy armor, you'll be slowed to 25', at which point the 80 feet of movement from your horse's two actions is faster than your 3 actions for 75 feet.

This is because of the [Minion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109) trait, which only allows companions to get 2 actions on your turn, taken when you Command the Animal. If the companion was not an animal companion (and instead was just a plain, tamed horse), you would be able to spend 3 actions to Command it on your turn and attempt the skill check, and if you succeeded it would use its 3 actions to Move as you commanded, as described in the [Command an Animal Activity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=58).

So it is mostly an unfortunate edge case, wherein a player with higher-than-standard movement speed can move faster than someone mounted on specifically an animal companion. If the character's movement was slightly lower due to armor or ancestry, or if the character was mounted on a non-animal companion, this edge case wouldn't manifest. Personally, this GM would allow you to use the Command an Animal's normal use-case (i.e. 1:1 action conversion) if you wanted to, instead of using the 2:1 Command an animal (so if you were riding full-speed, you'd spend 3 actions commanding your horse to move, and would go 120 feet).

Comment: I'd be cautious about that house rule as it effectively makes the Ranger's [Companion's Cry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=500) feat useless. Also, maxing at 4 actions potentially breaks the 3 action economy.

Comment: Yeah it would probably be better to restrict them to *either* Minion or standard Command an Animal functionality for a given round (they can either give them 2 actions for 1 or 3 actions for 3)

Comment: @cpcodes Hmm, I forgot about Companion's Cry. Since that's the case, I'll retract the houserule note.

Comment: @cpcodes isn't Companion's Cry useless anyway?

Comment: @András It may not be a must have, but it is situationally useful, like with the Wolf companion's Knockdown advanced maneuver if you need to move the companion and attack in the same turn.